# computed column DONOR.DonationTotal that reflects the lifetime contribution dollar amount for each donor

Tags: sql

**I am trying to write a computed column DONOR.DonationTotal that reflects the lifetime contribution dollar amount for each donor. (SQL**)
 My tables are

```
tbl Donor(contactID, NumberDonation, DonationTotal and DonorLevelID)

tbl Donation (DonationID, DonationDate, DonationAmount, VontactID) and 

tbl Donor_Level (DonorLevelID, DonorLevelName, DonorLevelMin, DonorLevelMax)
```

So my question is do I need to create a user defined function first or do I just write the computed column? How do I go about it? What I have so far is the following

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DONOR
   UPDATE DonationTotal (
```

Please help!

Comment: Or is it something like this                                                                                                            ALTER TABLE dbo.DONOR
  Add DonationTotal as (SELECT ContactID, SUM(DonationAmount)
     FROM DONATION DN
     JOIN DONOR D
      ON DN.ContactID = D.ContactID
     GROUP BY ContactID)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to drop the column before you can recreate it as a computed column. However, computed columns can only be defined using scalar expressions. I would create a VIEW that uses the subquery to calculate the value of the column.

You can check MSDN for more info about creating a computed column: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: So is it some thing like this                                                                                                
 ALTER TABLE DONOR
        DROP COLUMN DonationTotal 

 ALTER TABLE dbo.DONOR
  Add DonationTotal as (SELECT ContactID, SUM(DonationAmount)
     FROM DONATION DN
     JOIN DONOR D
      ON DN.ContactID = D.ContactID
     GROUP BY ContactID)

Comment: Yes, except for the part where you can't have a subquery as a computed column value. That's why I suggested the VIEW solution, as you can define the DonationTotal using the subquery you posted.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand

Comment: You can't use a subquery to define a computed column. You'll need to use a different approach. Check my new answer on creating a view.

Comment: Thank you that is help full, but am asked to particularly use computed column. That is what made it confusing to me as well.

Comment: What is the reasoning for requiring a computed column?

Comment: getting ready for a test and this was one of the practice questions given, i can ask the same question but wanted to know if i am missing something before asking?

Comment: I just had another idea. You could create a UDF that returns a scalar DonationTotal, for a passed in contact ID. Then use the function in the computed column. I can't test now, but that could be a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a temp table first and then updating donor from there. So something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (contactID int, donationtotal decimal);

INSERT INTO temp
SELECT donor.contactID, SUM(donation.donationamount)
FROM donor
INNER JOIN donation ON donor.contactID = donation.contactID
GROUP BY donor.contactID;

UPDATE donor
SET donor.donationamount =
(SELECT temp.donationamount
 FROM temp
 WHERE temp.contactID = donor.contactID)
```

Comment: I believe the intention is that the value of DonationTotal is always up-to-date. With this solution, you'd have to run the UPDATE statement every time a record in Donation is added/deleted/modified.

Comment: You're right. This one is meant to be a one time activity. I can't really tell from the question what the intention is...

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use a computed column here, you could make a view instead, and use the view instead of the table:

```
CREATE VIEW vwDonor
AS
SELECT do.contactID
       ,do.NumberDonation
       ,(SELECT SUM(DonationAmount) 
          FROM DONATION DN 
          JOIN DONOR D ON DN.ContactID = D.ContactID 
          WHERE D.ContactID = do.contactID 
          GROUP BY D.ContactID) 
        AS DonationTotal
       ,do.DonorLevelID
FROM Donor do
```